# Extract Data From ViewModel

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I have a view model:

```
public class CreateRepositoryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Repository _repository;
    public Repository Repository
    {
        get => _repository;
        set
        {
            _repository = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }
}
```

(BaseViewModel implements IPropertyChanged interface to simplify)

I have then bound the view model to my page like so:

```
DataContext = new CreateRepositoryViewModel();
```

I then have multiple form fields which are bound to the ViewModel:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Path=Repository.LicenceTemplate}" />
<CheckBox IsChecked="{Binding Path=Repository.HasIssues}" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
```

On a button click event model within the page I am attempting to extract the data like so:

```
var model = (CreateRepositoryViewModel) DataContext;
```

However, the Repository property within the data context is returning null. How can I obtain this data in the .cs file behind the xaml page?

Comment: This is the same page instance yes, what other details are required? The data context call is being made from the class behind the page's xaml file which contains the controls which are bound to the view model.

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. The Repository property within the DataContext is null. I will edit my question.

Comment: Why do you think it should not be null? You don't seem to be assigning a value anywhere. `private Repository _repository;` is null unless you assign a value.

Comment: The Property Changed method should populate the objects properties when the controls text is updated via the bindings, if I recall correctly.

Comment: For "*should populate the objects properties*" there must be an oject, i.e. a non-null Repository value.

Comment: I. E. Instantiate the Repository property?

Comment: No need to patronise. Was just a question.

Comment: Was just a clarification.

Comment: Thanks, I'll look at what the output displays and then update my question accordingly.

Comment: There is no need to update the question. Your problem *obviously* is that the Repository property is null. And the solution is trivial: assign a value. My hint was meant as a general advice. Take a close look before you ask trivial things.

Comment: I've returned back to my pc and solved the issue. The stack hint below comments does say ```Comments are used to ask for clarification``` so I don't see what the problem is with me clarifying what you'd told me - regardless of whether the question is trivial to you or not.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Repository property in ViewModel requires instantiating.

```
DataContext = new CreateRepositoryViewModel { Repository = new Models.Repository() };
```

Alternatively, assign a non-null initial value to the property's backing field.

```
public class CreateRepositoryViewModel : BaseViewModel
{
    private Repository _repository = new Models.Repository();
    ...
}
```

Then this is sufficient:

```
DataContext = new CreateRepositoryViewModel();
```